# Oracle: Update where error

Tags: sql, oracle

Good morning community.

I have been using MSSQL for a while, and have not had this issue with MSSQL, so it seems to be a way Oracle handles sql. Basically, I need to update two columns in the Table DANIEL_ALERT, based on the where condition. However, I get the " ORA-00904: "ALERT_CATEORIES"."ALERT": invalid identifier. I am sure it is just the way oracle does things which is different to MSSQL.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

```
UPDATE DANIEL_ALERT
SET DANIEL_ALERT.ALERT_CATEGORY = ALERT_CATEGORIES.INDICATION,
DANIEL_ALERT.ALERT_THEME = ALERT_CATEGORIES.THEME
WHERE DANIEL_ALERT.ALERT_NAME = ALERT_CATEGORIES.ALERT;
commit;
```

Comment: In the StackOverflow documentation domain: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201702100111008140877

Comment: Could you please also post the table DANIEL_ALERT structure here?

Comment: this wouldn't work in MSSQL either: `ALERT_CATEGORIES` is not mentioned as a participating table

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what your table structures and content looks like, you could go with this approach, to go along with, or as an alternative to the perfectly fine `MERGE` answer already posted:

```
UPDATE DANIEL_ALERT DA
SET (DA.ALERT_CATEGORY, DA.ALERT_THEME) = (
    SELECT AC.INDICATION, AC.THEME 
    FROM ALERT_CATEGORIES AC 
    WHERE AC.ALERT = DA.ALERT_NAME
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM ALERT_CATEGORIES AC
    WHERE AC.ALERT = DA.ALERT_NAME
);
```

Comment: This looks right to me, although I don't like the `select null` in the `exists` subquery.

Comment: It looks odd, but it works just the same as `select 1` or `select 'x'`, I've just always been in the habit of doing it this way, stylistically right or wrong. =)

Comment: . . It is not "wrong".  I am just opposed to `null` being counted as something valid.  I think it is inconsistent with the general treatment of `NULL` in SQL.  Anything else is preferable (I always use `1`).

Answer (score 0):

try :

> UPDATE DANIEL_ALERT
>    SET t1.ALERT_CATEGORY = t2.INDICATION,
>    t1.ALERT_THEME = t2.THEME 
>   FROM DANIEL_ALERT t1 
>   INNER JOIN ALERT_CATEGORIES t2 ON t2.ALERT = t1.ALERT_NAME

Comment: That syntax will not work in Oracle. I already posted a link to the correct syntax in a comment below the original post.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, updating a table with values from another table is often best done with the `MERGE` statement. Something like:

```
merge into DANIEL_ALERT d
  using ALERT_CATEGORIES c
     on (d.ALERT_NAME = c.ALERT)
when matched then update 
   set ALERT_CATEGORY = c.INDICATION,
       ALERT_THEME    = c.THEME
;
```